# image of the complement subset of complement of image

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $f : G \to H$.

Is it true that $f(M)^c \subset f(M^c)$ for $M \subset G$? Is the result ever true—i.e., is it true if we impose the condition that $f$ is bijective?

Comment: Have you tried the exercise? If you are wondering what you should first try proving, try drawing pictures of possible situations.

Comment: I have tried yes I found counter example to when it is injective but I couldn't find any of it is surjective.

Comment: I think it is true if f is surjective.

Comment: So how would you start the proof for that?

Comment: I just pick an element in $f(M)^c$ and show it is an element of $f(M^c)$. But I am getting problems

Comment: What is the relation between $f(M^c)$ and $f(M)$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the statement would be true then $H=f(M)\cup f(M)^c=f(M)\cup f(M^c)$.

This states that $f$ is surjective

---

Conversely if $f$ is surjective then for every $y\in H$ we can find some $x\in G$ with $y=f(x)$.

If moreover $y\in f(M)^c$ then evidently $x\in M^c$, hence $y=f(x)\in f(M^c)$.

---

Final conclusion: the statement is true if and only if $f$ is surjective.

Comment: why is $x \in M^c$ ?

Comment: I can see it from picture but why does it follow from the above ?

Comment: If $x\notin M^c$ then $x\in M$ so that $y=f(x)\in f(M)$, contradicting $y\in f(M)^c$.

Comment: @drhab can i repeat your 2nd part other way round thus proving subset from both sides to proof the equality holds ? Also i think inverse image behave better way as $(f^{-1}(G))^{c}=f^{-1}(G^{c})$ is quite easy to verify.

Comment: @NewBornMATH Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. In the second part of my answer (starting with "Conversely") it is proved that $f(M)^{\complement}\subseteq f(M^{\complement})$ or equivalently that $H=f(M)\cup f(M^{\complement})$. In what sense do you want to "repeat" my second part? Indeed $f^{-1}(G)^{\complement}=f^{-1}(G^{\complement})$ (preimages behave much nicer than images), but that is not quite relevant here, is it?

Answer (score 5):

@Dude (maybe 4 years too late but still useful), if you impose that f is surjective and injective then you can conclude that both sets are equal. You can show the missing subset property "$\supseteq$" as follows:

Let be y $\in f(M^c) \Rightarrow f^{-1}(y) \in M^c$ (this is because f is injective and y has exactly one preimage) $\Rightarrow f^{-1}(y) \notin M \Rightarrow y \notin f(M) \Rightarrow y \in f(M)^c$. The other subset property "$\subseteq$" was already proven by drhab

Comment: Do we need bijectiveness to conclude "$\supseteq$" or does this inclusion hold in general iff $f$ is injective? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3980132/47771

Comment: @0xbadf00d, No you don't need bijectiveness (bijectivity?) if you only want to show the "$\supseteq$" property. However, if you want to show the equality then you do need both properties and hence a bijective function.