# Is the complement of image equivalent to the image of the complement?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

> Let $f:X \to Y$ and $B\subseteq X$. Prove or disprove $f(\overline B)=\overline{f(B)}$, where $f(B)$ is the image of $B$ in $f$.

I thought it was false, but my counterexamples proved me wrong, so I need help in proving it is true.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Suppose $f$ is a constant.

Comment: Examples of something happening don't prove something always happens.

Comment: Or that f is not surjective...

Comment: @JonasMeyer They aren't trying to prove something always happens, it's a counter-example establishing that it doesn't happen all the time. That's sufficient to conclude that the statement is false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [image of the complement subset of complement of image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447524/image-of-the-complement-subset-of-complement-of-image)

Comment: Do you mean complement as you stated in the title or closure as you wrote in the message?

Comment: @CyclotomicField: It says, "I thought it was false, but my counterexamples proved me wrong." That shows incorrect use of examples, concluding that the identity does hold because it held in some examples.  It would be correct to use examples to prove that the identity doesn't hold, but that is not what was done.

Comment: @William: In this context it appears $\overline A$ is used to mean the complement of $A$.

Comment: It meas closure.  $A^{c}$ is the complement.

Comment: @William: Different notations are used by different people at times.  One of the notations used for complement sometimes, including in this question, is $\overline{A}$.  Likewise there are other notations sometimes used for closure.  We have to be versatile to adjust for different uses despite desires for uniformity.  Even $\subset$ means different things at different times.  In the context of this question there is no topology context to indicate that closure is even meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three mutually exclusive possibilities:

(A) For all $X,Y,f,B$, we have the equality $f(\overline B)=\overline{f(B)}$.
(B) For all $X,Y,f,B$, we have the inequality $f(\overline B)\neq\overline{f(B)}$.
(C) Sometimes $f(\overline B)=\overline{f(B)}$, and other times $f(\overline B)\neq\overline{f(B)}$.

The original question asks you to prove whether (A) is true or false. If (A) is false, then you don't necessarily have to decide whether (B) or (C) is true.

> I thought it was false, but my counterexamples proved me wrong...

...Okay, that means you investigated some particular counterexample $X,Y,f,B$, and you computed that $f(\overline B)=\overline{f(B)}$ after all. And you did this a few times.

These counterexamples prove that (B) is false. That's progress!

> ...so I need help in proving it is true.

Not quite. **For all you know at this point, either (A) or (C) could still be true.** So your next task isn't necessarily to prove (A).

In fact, it turns out that (A) is false, and the truth is (C): Sometimes $f(\overline B)=\overline{f(B)}$, and other times $f(\overline B)\neq\overline{f(B)}$. Consider, for example, the function $f(x)=42$.