# Show that $f(A)^c\subseteq f(A^c)$ if and only if $f$ is injective

Tags: functions

Let $E_i$ be a set, $f:E_1\to E_2$ and $A\subseteq E_1$.

It is easy to show (see, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1447826/47771) that $f(A)^c\subseteq f(A^c)$ if and only if $f$ is surjective.

Are we able to show that

> $f(A^c)\subseteq f(A)^c$ if and only if $f$ is injective

as well? (It's quite easy to prove $f(A^c)=f(A)^c$ if $f$ is bijective; see, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3301866/47771.)

Comment: If $A$ is (arbitrary but) fixed, then no. But $f$ is injective iff $f(A^c) \subseteq f(A)^c$ holds for *all* $A \subseteq E_1$.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: The title and question don't seem to match.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. Somehow surprisingly, since the analogue surjectivity result holds for a fixed $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will denote $X = E_1$ and $Y = E_2$ and $f:X \rightarrow Y$.

Suppose $f$ is injective. Let $y \in f[X\setminus A]$ be arbitrary. Then, there exists $x_1 \in X\setminus A$, equivalently $x_1 \not\in A$, such that $f(x_1) = y$. Now, suppose there is $x_2 \in A$ such that $f(x_2) = y$. Then, $x_1 \neq x_2$ and this means $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$ by injectivity, which is a contradiction. So, for all $x \in A$, $f(x) \neq y$, which means $y \not\in f[A]$, equivalently $y \in Y\setminus f[A]$.

Suppose $f[X\setminus A] \subseteq Y\setminus f[A]$. Let $x_1 \neq x_2$ be elements of $X$ and assume $X$ has at least two elements. Then, there is a subset $A$ of $X$ such that $x_1\in A$ and $x_2\not\in A$. Then, we immediately have $f(x_1) \in f[A]$. $x_2 \in X\setminus A$ implies $f(x_2) \in f[X\setminus A] \subseteq Y\setminus f[A]$, that is, $f(x_2) \not\in f[A]$. Therefore, $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see. Did I get something wrong or does the analogue surjectivity claim hold for a fixed $A$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'fixed'?

Comment: I mean that if $A\subseteq E_1$ is fixed, then "$f(A)^c\subseteq f(A^c)$ if and only $f$ is surjective".

Comment: I am sorry, I was late. Yes, $A$ as a subset of $X$ can be universally quantified. I should have said that "Suppose that for each $A \subseteq X$, $f[X\setminus A]...$ in the third paragraph.