# Comparing $f(A^c)$ with $f(A)^c$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

Given a map of sets $f: X \to Y$ and $A \subset X$, I'm trying to solve a problem that asks for the relationship between $f(A^c)$ and $f(A)^c$. I believe the correct relationships are:

> (i) $f(A^c) \subset f(A)^c$ if and only if $f$ is injective;
>
> (ii) $f(A)^c \subset f(A^c)$ if and only if $f$ is surjective;
>
> (iii) $f(A^c) = f(A)^c$ if and only if $f$ is bijective.

(iii) follows immediately from (i) and (ii), so I'm going to try to prove (i) and (ii).

**Proof of (i)**

> Suppose $f$ is injective, and let $y \in f(A^c)$. then $y = f(x')$ for some $x' \in A^c$. Then $y \not \in f(x)$ for any $x \in A$; indeed, if $x \in A$, $x \not \in A^c$, so $x \neq x'$, so by injectivity, $f(x) \neq f(x') = y$. Therefore, $y \not \in f(A)$, so $y \in f(A)$, so $f(A^c) \subset f(A)^c$.

I'm struggling with the converse. My instinct is to proceed by contraposition, supposing $f$ is not injective and finding $x \neq x'$ such that $f(x) = y = f(x')$. I then tried to define $A = \{x\}$, so $x' \in A^c$, so $y = f(x) \in f(A)$ and $y = f(x') \in f(A^c)$, but that doesn't help because I'm not working with $f(A)^c$. I need to find an element of $f(A^c)$ that isn't in $f(A)^c$.

**Proof of (ii)**

> Suppose $f$ is surjective, and let $y \in f(A)^c$. As $f$ is surjective, there exists some $x \in X$, such that $f(x) = y$. As $y\in f(A)^c$, $y \not \in f(A)$, so $x \not \in A$. Therefore, $x \in A^c$, so $y \in f(A^c)$, and we have $f(A)^c \subset f(A)^c$.

I'm again struggling with the converse. I again tried to proceed by contraposition. Suppose that $f$ is not surjective, so there exists $y \in Y$ such that $y \not \in f(X)$. This didn't yield any progress, because I have no sense for how I should define $A$ and $A^c$.

I would greatly appreciate some feedback, especially on the converse directions. If contraposition isn't the correct approach, how else should I proceed?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I'm very sorry, but I'm not sure I understand where I've done this. Could you explain further?

Comment: [surjective (1st answer)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1447524/image-of-the-complement-subset-of-complement-of-image/1447826#1447826) and [injective](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3980132/show-that-fac-subseteq-fac-if-and-only-if-f-is-injective?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I think I understand. The set $A$ is fixed at the start of the problem. I tried to define a set $A$ in my proof by contraposition, which adds a universal quantifier in front of the $A$ and is a completely different statement. Is that right?

Comment: @david_sap Very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio So the only thing I can say with $A$ fixed is the backward direction? So if $f$ is injective, then $f(A^c) \subset f(A)^c$, and if $f$ is surjective, then $f(A)^c \subset f(A^c)$.